# Logging into my node app's server as a root user

Tags: node.js

I am trying to set up a simple CI/CD Pipeline for my app with Jenkins but am having difficulty logging into my node app's server as a root user following the instructions provided.

I am following [this article](https://medium.com/@mosheezderman/how-to-set-up-ci-cd-pipeline-for-a-node-js-app-with-jenkins-c51581cc783c).
Here's a [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wLVNo.png) to an image for where I'm getting hung up.

Here's what I've tried in my terminal:

- Entering `ssh root@NODE.SERVER.IP` verbatim into the terminal. (received response: `ssh: Could not resolve hostname node.server.ip: nodename nor servname provided, or not known`)
- Entering `ssh root@172.20.20.20` the terminal seems to become unresponsive to the following commands i.e. (`adduser <lastname>`)

Comment: did you change `NODE.SERVER.IP` to the IP of your droplet? Its a little unclear, what you mean by you ssh'ed in and node launched? you mean you got a console prompt?

Comment: @LawrenceCherone I did not change the NODE.SERVER.IP in anyway (what I did do was download a npm package that allowed me to easily access the current IP and I entered that). 

As for saying node launched, it did not (originally thought that the angle bracket displayed indicating I was in the node environment). What's happening is that the terminal seems to become unresponsive.